# How to add button role to a custom element in angular to make it accessible by screen reader?

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a custom component in angular that handles images. I have alt text as an input to the element and the screen reader picks it up to utter it out. But whenever I tab to the image, it says 'Trash' group. I want the screen reader to read it out as 'Trash' button. How can I achieve this? The following is my current implementation:

Icn component:

```
<img [ngClass]="class" [file]="file" [alt]="alt">
```

Usage:

```
<icn class="del-icon" [file]="'trash'" [alt]="Trash"></icn>
```

I tried role="button" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Angular so you may need to do some digging on how to structure this but your approach is making things difficult.

Instead make the button a `<button>`. This way you get all the native accessibility built in (e.g. accessible via tab by default, accepts focus, has `hover` and `focus` states etc.)and you will also get the correct announcements in screen readers.

Then place the icon inside the `<button>` and just style it appropriately.

```
<button> <!--add whatever directives angular requires here-->
   <img [ngClass]="class" [file]="file" [alt]="alt">
</button>
```

Also you may consider using inline SVGs for your icons as they offer styling options and can change colour according to user preferences. It is also one less resource to download so will help with performance.

Comment: Ah, I have my current component being used in 100's of places. That approach wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Without knowing the whole story I can only offer suggestions, but why not make a new component and start using that everywhere, then whenever you refactor a part of the system just replace it then. I normally do a `find` across the project for things that need improving and then just add a <!--todo: replace with x--> above each item. Either that or bite the bullet, if this component is used as a button everywhere then swap it out, short term pain for better maintainability is nearly always worth it.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this problem by experimenting more with the roles.

The image tag doesn't take the role="button" as an attribute. Instead, the role needs to be assigned to the parent element of the image tag i.e., in my case the component `icn` like follows:

```
<icn class="del-icon" role="button" [file]="'trash'" [alt]="Trash"></icn>
```

Now, the screen reader software reads out as the 'Trash button' and gives further more instructions on how to interact with the button. And also if the above doesn't work, just by encapsulating the custom component in a span tag and assigning the `role="button"` to the span tag works like a charm.

```
<span class="del-btn-container" role="button">
   <icn class="del-icon" [file]="'trash'" [alt]="Trash"></icn>
</span>
```

Note: Button role [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/button/button.html)

Comment: Adding an aria role is a promise to the user that you will handle the expected  interactions so make sure to follow the [interaction guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#button).

Comment: Absolutely. I am already in the process of getting that done :)

Comment: Option 1, fair enough given how many custom components you have, reasonable work around. Option 2 - don't do it - wrap it in a `<button>` and save yourself a load of headaches. Semantics are 70% of accessibility, don't use `WAI-ARIA` unless you have no other options, in this case you have plenty of options.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Will follow your advice :) Thanks a ton for correcting me :) Cheers

Comment: @ShellZero not a problem bud, the problem is examples make it confusing as they don't follow the best practices they are meant to be teaching (mainly because they are 10 years old so don't have HTML 5 and buttons etc. you can fully style. ). Good luck with the project!